# Importing multi-picklist values using data loader salesforce

Tags: data-loader, npsp

In my Salesforce Org. I have a custom field **multi-picklist** called Category. Then it has list values of (Y Connect, Board Member, Annual Report, Celebrity). I do an import recently and the imports are successful and data's are pretty perfect as I expected. Then after that I imported 20+ additional contact data, these data has value of not active in the **multi-picklist** field(Category) called **Y Connect Member** . So I'm pretty sure that the org's multi-picklist(category) existing value **Y Connect** is different from my new contact category value **Y Connect Member** . So I expected that my csv's new category value will temporarily added into the list  [by this documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_on_importing_data.htm&language=en) . But at the end when I view the 20+ additional contacts, the category are missing, it leaves blank. Can anyone give me some brilliant idea's why is it happening and what should I do to fix this issue ?

regards,

Danryl